# Python：Why is plt.axhline(y=0.0 ...) not at y=0?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Why does the same code produce different results when run in PyCharm and VSCode, even though the environments are both configured with Anaconda?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeR2B.png)

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define parameters
N = 1e7  # Total population
lamuda = 0.2  # Average number of contacts per day
mu = 0.08  # Probability of being cured and recovered is 0.08
I0 = 100  # Initial number of infected individuals
i0 = I0 / N  # Initial proportion of infected individuals
s0 = (N - I0) / N  # Initial proportion of susceptible individuals
tend = 200  # Prediction days is 200
t = np.arange(0.0, tend, 1)  # (start, stop, step)

# SIR model:
def dySIR(y, t, lamuda, mu):
    i, s = y
    di_dt = lamuda * s * i - mu * i
    ds_dt = -lamuda * s * i
    return [di_dt, ds_dt]

# Recovered individuals proportion is represented by 1 - s - i
Y0 = (i0, s0)  # Set initial values

# Numerical solution of the equations
ySIR = odeint(dySIR, Y0, t, args=(lamuda, mu))

# Plotting
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.axis([0, tend, -0.1, 1.1])
plt.axhline(y=0.0 ,ls="--",c='c')  # Add horizontal line
plt.plot(t, ySIR[:,0], '-r', label='i(t)-SIR')
plt.plot(t, ySIR[:,1], '-b', label='s(t)-SIR')
plt.plot(t, 1 - ySIR[:,0] - ySIR[:,1], '-m', label='r(t)-SIR')
plt.legend(loc='best')  
plt.show()
```

The issue lies in this line of code: `plt.axhline(y=0.0 ,ls="--",c='c')`

vscode:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysrjd.png)

pycharm:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaCW9.png)

Both the VSCode and PyCharm environments are configured with Anaconda using Python 3.11.7.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same versions of Matplotlib, Numpy and Scipy in both VS Code and Pycharm?